# Return array of deleted elements postgresql JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

This is my database:

```
dragons
id, key, name, age, creation_date
```

```
users
id, name, user, pass
```

```
users_dragons
user_id, dragon_id
```

So this is my code for deleting dragons from the database that have a bigger key that the passed and belongs to a determination user. The SQL query works perfectly for deleting them but not for returning the array of keys from the deleted elements.

I tried using `PreparedStatement` but later I checked, as far as I know, that this class doesn't return arrays, and the `CallableStatement` is only for executing processes in the db, and I don't know how they return arrays.

```
String query = "" +
"DELETE FROM dragons " +
"WHERE id IN (SELECT d.id FROM dragons d, users u, users_dragons ud" +
"         WHERE d.key > ?" +
"           AND ud.dragon_id = d.iD" +
"           AND ud.user_id in (select id from users where id = ?)) RETURNING key INTO ?";

CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(query);
int pointer = 0;
callableStatement.setInt(++pointer, key);
callableStatement.setInt(++pointer, credentials.id);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(++pointer, Types.INTEGER);
callableStatement.executeUpdate();

return (int []) callableStatement.getArray(1).getArray();
```

The code is giving me the error, but is obvious because the CallableStatement needs a postgres function to run and not a simple SQL query

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement does not declare an OUT parameter. 
Use { ?= call ... } to declare one. 
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.registerOutParameter
.......
```

It would be really helpful how would be the correct JDBC algorithm to delete the elements from the database and return the array of keys of the deleted items.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You treat such a statement like a normal `SELECT` statement: use `java.sql.PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` or `java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(String sql)` to execute the statement and get a result set.

`java.sql.CallableStatement` is for calling Procedures (but you don't need it in PostgreSQL).